Did Carroll actually miss the catch?
On 5/13/2024 (I think) during the Reds Diamondbacks game, Corbin Carroll performed what looked to be an awesome sliding catch that the Reds apparently challenged and overturned. I was watching the highlight reel that did not show the sequence of challenging. It just cut to the next clip where the sportscaster mentioned the overturn. I'm not convinced Carroll didn't actually catch it, since the ball appeared to be in his glove at the moment of the drop.

Unless we see a video how are we to even have an opinion? Do you have a link? And in general, while of course the officials are not infallible, the standard is incontrovertible evidence. So if the imp called out and it was overturned, they had to have seen something like the ball hitting the ground.

I found a video of it on the MLB app. It was the third batter in the top of the 8th. The “live” shot is far and from a home plate angle and hard to tell- looks like a catch. At the end of the video they show a side angle closer up and the ball bounces in the grass just a few inches in front of the glove and bounces right into the glove. Safe.

For reference: https://www.mlb.com/dbacks/video/jeimer-candelario-lines-into-a-double-play-center-fielder-corbin-carroll-x3604
